# NSButton imagePosition not working

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, appkit

I am setting the property [imagePosition](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButtonCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSButtonCell/imagePosition) of NSButton to `ImageOnly`.
The type of `imagePosition` is [NSCellImagePosition](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/c:@E@NSCellImagePosition)

---

### When I set the imagePosition to `ImageOnly`, it still displays the title of the button, although the description clearly states

> The cell displays an image, but not a title.

IB also hides the title but when executed the title is seen.
Is this a known bug or I am doing anything wrong ?

---

Note: This problem persistent even if the NSButton is created programmatically.

---

Edit: My open source repo [KSTabView](https://github.com/kaunteya/KSTabView/tree/test) on github has this bug. When Only is selected still the title and Image, both are visible.

Comment: Are you sure the reference to the button is not nil?  I.e. are you sure your outlet is connected correctly?  And are you sure imagePosition is not getting set to a different value somewhere in your code?  Countless apps create countless image-only buttons that work fine, so the probability is extremely high that this is a bug in your code, not a problem with Cocoa.  Post code please; you say the problem occurs even with programmatic creation of the NSButton, please post the code demonstrating that.

Comment: @bhaller: I have made the edit.
You can check my library. It has both Programatically and IB added buttons to demonstrate my problem

Comment: Since this is Swift, I'll leave it someone else to look at; I don't know Swift.  You should tag the question with the swift tag.

Comment: This question is about the Cocoa framework not about the Swift programming language.

Comment: The code that you posted is Swift code.  Tagging a question with "swift" does not indicate that the question is *about* Swift (just as you tagged with osx even though your question is not *about* OS X); it indicates that the question *involves* Swift.  Which would have been useful in preventing me from wasting my time and yours, given that I am not a Swift programmer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the standard push button ignores the text position you're setting in IB. Sometimes I just hate the IB because of issues that. It has so much bugs...

Now you either just delete the title in IB or you force that the cell doesn't draw any title like:

```
override func drawTitle(title: NSAttributedString, withFrame frame: NSRect, inView controlView: NSView) -> NSRect {

    return super.drawTitle(NSAttributedString(string: ""), withFrame: frame, inView: controlView)
}
```

Comment: Another workaround: override `initWithCoder` and set `imagePosition` to `ImageOnly`.